# What is the logging location for Synergy on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, synergy

Where does **[Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/)** log to?  I'm on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the FAQ for synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/pm/projects/synergy/wiki/UserFAQ#Q-How-do-I-send-you-guys-debug-output):

> Windows you'll need to use the special console window (accessed via the system tray).

Check out the link for more information.